# Change tag content with array elements on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

how can I loop inner HTML of with each array element on each button click?

https://jsfiddle.net/s0toedfh/2/

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"]; $("p").html(fruits[0]);

$( "button" ).click(function() { $("p").html(fruits[1]); });
```

Comment: Use a counter https://jsfiddle.net/xLaajjm7/

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"]; 
var index=0;

$( "button" ).click(function() {
    $("p").html(fruits[index]);
    index++;
    if(index>=fruits.length)index=0;
});
```

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var index = 0;

$("button").click(function() {
  $("p").html(fruits[index]);
  index++;
  if (index >= fruits.length) index = 0;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>

</p>
<br>
<button>
click
</button>
```

**Alternatively,** you can try,

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"],
    index = 0,
    totalFruits=fruits.length;

$("button").click(function() {
    $("p").html(fruits[index++ % totalFruits]); // increment and get index
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>

</p>
<br>
<button>
click
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Rohan, Your solution working like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a variable to count the number of times the click happened.

The variable defined outside may be initialized as 0 and on every click, it can be incremented by and do a `modulo` with the length of the fruits list to make sure it always stays between 0-length_of_fruits

Here is an implementation

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

$("p").html(fruits[0]);

var count = 0
$("button").click(function() {
  count = (count + 1) % fruits.length
  $("p").html(fruits[count]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
<br>
<button>  click  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

A more simpler one:

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var index = 0;

$("button").click(function() {
  $("p").html(fruits[index%fruits.length]);
  index++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<br>
<button>
click
</button>
```